# Minimum 4 Characters or Show Nothing - PHP

Tags: php, character-limit

I want to show up only words with **minimum** 4 Characters, actually I can limit the hits and show only words with min. 100 hits - but how can I set a min. character length? thank you!

```
function sm_list_recent_searches($before = '', $after = '', $count = 20) {
// List the most recent successful searches.
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
    $count = intval($count);
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT `terms`, `datetime`
        FROM `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent`
        WHERE 100 < `hits`
        ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
        LIMIT $count");
    if (count($results)) {

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo '<a href="'. get_settings('home') . '/search/' . urlencode($result->terms) . '">'. htmlspecialchars($result->terms) .'</a>'.", ";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mySQL:

```
WHERE 100 < `hits` AND CHAR_LENGTH('yourField') > 4
```

Comment: plussing this, as it was first and I mixed up length with char_length

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length):

> **CHAR_LENGTH(str)**
>   Returns the length of the string str, measured in characters. A multi-byte character counts as a single character. This means that for a string containing five two-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.

So you add

```
where(char_length(terms) > 4))
```